# A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field: Creating object from { get; set; } result

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand a concept and I'm not sure how to go about it.  I would really appreciate some help.

What I am trying to do is pull data from a comma separated text file and then use what I pulled to create another object.  For example, I want to determine the weeklyWage for a 40 hour week using the hourly wage.  If I pulled in the hourly wage from the text file with a { get; set; } is there a way to then say "weeklyWage = hourlyWage * 40"?

```
public class employee 
{
     public double hourlyWage { get; set; }  
     public double weeklyWage = hourlyWage * 40;
}
```

error: field initializer cannot reference the non-static field

Comment: You need to convert weeklywage to property. `public double weeklyWage {get{return hourlyWage * 40;}}`

Comment: you can fix this with a single character actually - `public double weeklyWage => hourlyWage * 40;`. It turns the declaration into a get-method of a property rather than a one-time definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have here is related to the fact that compiler is not aware what is the value of hourlyWage property at the moment field weeklyWage is inializing; so it gives you an error. It (value for weeklyWage) is suppossed to be set from your code, while parsing text file or dynamically calculated. So 2 easy options you to have:

1. You might use setters of hourlyWage:

   ```
   public class employee    
   {
      // This is "backing field" for hourly wage
      private double _hourlyWage;
      // And this is actual property, where business logic happens
      public double hourlyWage
      {
          get
          {
              return _hourlyWage;
          }
          set
          {
              // Set both _hourlyWage and weeklyWage at once
              _hourlyWage = value;
              weeklyWage = _hourlyWage * 40;
          }
      }
      // Public for get, private for set (r
      public double weeklyWage { get; private set; }
   }
   ```
2. Or you might want to use dynamic getter:

   ```
   public class employee
   {                
           public double hourlyWage{get;set;}    
           public double weeklyWage { get { return hourlyWage * 40; } }
           // "modern" getter syntax would look this way:
           // public double weeklyWage => hourlyWage * 40;
           // Still used "old" syntax for being more expressive.
           // The choice is yours.
   }
   ```

I would prefer first approach, as value for weeklyWage is calculated once, at the moment hourlyWage is set.

Comment: The advantage of the latter is that it is _possible_ with the former to set `_hourlyWage` and forget to set `weeklyWage`.

Comment: @mjwills - while trading the fact that it's always calculated again and again (plus the "set" is encapsulating our BL...). But there is always a trade, so valid tip, thanks!

Comment: That seems to have done it, I used the second option you gave to use the dynamic getter.   Thank you!!